# How can i get access to elements of string array inside of a stream?

Tags: java, arrays, split, java-stream

I need to count and sort hashtags inside string using stream api.

example:

```
 String posts = "Example #java #streams string etc."
```

I've tried to split this string to String[] and then iterate elements on condition " if index(0).equals("#") then ...

But i can't get access to elements of String[] itself inside of a stream.

```
posts.stream()
     .map(i -> i.split(""))
     .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(i).allMatch(x -> x.substring(0).equals("#")))
```

In code above i = String[], not String. So:
How can i get String[] elements by index inside of a stream?

thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. After the map, you will have a `Stream<String[]>`  if you want to filter it based on a specific element, you can do it like this: `.filter(arr -> arr[0]...)`. What is the final goal? to keep the words starting with "#" ?

Comment: `Arrays .stream(posts.split(" ")) .filter(w -> w.startsWith("#")) .collect(Collectors.toList())`. GIves `[#java, #streams]`.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to count and sort hashtags inside string using stream api.

I don't understand anything about your attempt; to start, string objects like `posts` don't have a `stream()` method, and the rest just seems like a bunch of random stuff with no rhyme or reason... I think you're really confused about some things and/or making it more complicated than it needs to be, so here's a small simple example that extracts hashtags from a string in sorted order, with comments describing each step:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String posts = "Example #java #streams string etc.";

        // Define a hashtag as a # followed by one or more alphanumeric
        // characters and a word boundary.
        Pattern hashtag_re = Pattern.compile("#[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\b");

        List<String> hashtags =
            hashtag_re.matcher(posts).results() // Stream of MatchResult objects
            .map(MatchResult::group) // Extract the matched text from each;
                                     // now a stream of Strings
            .sorted() // Sort the tags
            .distinct() // Remove duplicates
            .toList(); // Convert to a list (Old versions of java might need
                       // .collect(Collectors.toList()) instead)

        System.out.println("There are "
                           + hashtags.size()
                           + " hashtags: "
                           + hashtags);
    }

}
```

when run will display

```
$ java Foo.java
There are 2 hashtags: [#java, #streams]
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to @Shawn's answer is to convert your pattern into a predicate used for filtering the stream:

```
String posts = "Example #java #streams string etc."
Pattern delim = Pattern.compile(" +");
Predicate<String> isHash = Pattern.compile("#.*").asMatchPredicate();
delim.splitAsStream(posts).filter(isHash)
    ...
```

The results are equivalent